# Site does not load for some customers after some time if served from cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have site resources like js, css and images hosted on S3 with Cloudfront distribution site's headers has cloudfront CDN url to load resources. Site is working fine and loads properly but some customers reported that site is not loading anymore, it was working 1 day before. Clearing cache did not work. On the cloudfront there is no method to check the issue. Any help will be appreciated.

This might get flagged as inappropriate question but I am not sure how and where to ask this as I have no clue about reasons and debugging methods for it.

Comment: If you open CloudFront distribution you should be able to see the % of requests dropped or returning an error (like 404 or 500), is it abnormally high?

Comment: @Gapton Yes, about 2% misses and 2% errors, it is under cache statistics and  also in popular objects

Comment: see if [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1617045/dns-not-resolving-only-for-a-handful-of-people-after-10-days-and-even-via-goog) helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you have issues about TTL....this may help you
[AWS TTL solve](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html)